# corrected AIC (AICc) assumes the model is univariate?

Tags: model-selection, aic, assumptions

I'm considering using the AICc instead of the AIC to select models because my sample size is not much larger than my number of parameters (n=214, K=16 - which is not enough, according to [Burnham and Anderson](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/b97636.pdf) page 66).

However, whilst they don't really say much as to the assumptions we need to make in their book, wikipedia seem to indicate some of the assumptions we need to make on the model so that the formule for AICc holds:
[image]

I don't understand what `assuming that the model is univariate` mean. I'm doing variable selection, across 16 variables (I plan on fixing many of them, because otherwise I'll just have overfitting) and **I know** that my model is not univariate. Otherwise I would just compare the 16 models with one variable.

Furthermore, I'm not sure how I can verify the other assumptions (them being: `Assuming that the model [...] is linear in its parameters, and has normally-distributed residuals (conditional upon regressors)`).

Comment: i suspect they mean the response y is univariate i.e. not vector regression.

Comment: Like predicting a float rather than a vector?

Comment: yes (comment is now of sufficient length to post thanks to this parenthetical that may be ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here they are referring to a model in which the *response variable* is univariate (as opposed to a response vector) (hat tip to [John Madden](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/82893/) for pointing this out in comments).  The formula given covers simple and multiple linear regression, but not multivariate regression.

In terms of the other assumptions, you should note that the AIC and AICc can be written in terms of the underlying maximised log-likelihood function for your model.  Consequently, if you are using a regression model that is nonlinear, or which uses a non-Gaussian error distribution, you can still derive the formulae for the AIC and AICc, but you need to go through the process of looking at the log-likelihood function for your model.  An example of the derivation of the AIC (for a Gaussian regression) is in [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566801/).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Basically means that if I'm using a "standard" linear regression model that predicts one variable, my model is linear in its parameters, and has normally-distributed residuals? What if I'm doing a logistic regression? Would that change anything?

Comment: Yes, it would change things.  If you do logistic regression then your lieklihood function changes, with flow-on effects to the AIC.

Comment: So the definition of the AIC in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Definition) is only valid for a linear regression model? Phrased as it is, it sounds like it's valid for any model. Or are the flow-on effects only on the AICc?

Comment: No, that is the general definition; you will see that the definition depends on the maximised log-likelihood function.  If you change to a different model then you change your likelihood function, which changes the AIC.

Comment: Then why is this link giving another formula (with the /N)? https://machinelearningmastery.com/probabilistic-model-selection-measures/#:~:text=The%20AIC%20statistic%20is%20defined,LL%20%2B%202%20*%20k%2FN

Comment: Is it equivalent because it's just a factor away from the original formula and the only thing we're interested in anyway is the delta AIC? (statement taken from MODEL SELECTION AND MULTIMODEL INFERENCE by Burnham & Anderson)

Comment: The usual definition does not have the scaling factor $1/N$.  However, as you point out, we use this statistic only for relative comparisons, so a scaling factor does not mess this up.